# Wordpress Permalink Structure 301 Redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

Currently I am using Wordpress v3.4 and using the following Permalink Custom Structure

```
/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%.html
```

Now I want to remove .html from it so I did like this

```
/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

I want to 301 redirect from old structure to new one.

Does anyone have the solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [**Redirection WordPress plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) to manage 301 redirections, keep track of 404 errors, and generally tidy up any loose ends your site may have.

Comment: I have a total of 3,275 posts and with this plugin I will have to make 301 in every 3,275 posts, I was looking for something easier to do but if no other solution I'll have to use the plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should have never had put the extension, honestly I am surprised that Wordpress allowed this. However, if you change the permalink structure, usually it updates all previous posts and pages. Is that not the case here?

Comment: if I change I will have many elements wordpress 404 errors because it does not open the old urls.

Comment: Have you checked any of your directories to see if it created HTML files. Also, maybe you can do a sitewide export of posts and pages, then change the permalink structure delete all posts and pages, and then import the file?